# Not able to connect SQL Server 2008 Remotely

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-connection

I have setup SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition. It automatically contains my system name which is sipl006 as Servername. My system IP is 172.27.28.44. My issue is it is not connecting remotely with IP address because my database is also accessed by different domain and I need IP address to authenticate the application with my database. I have googled about this but no helps.

```
servername : sipl006
Authentication : Sql server authentication
username : sa
password : blablabla
```

```
I have already checked the below details


1. SIPL006 >> properties >> connection >> Allowed Remote connections. 
2. Sql server configuration Manager >> enable named pipes, TCP/IP, via etc. 
3. Confirm default port 1433.
4. Firewall is already off.
```

I have only MSSQLServer instance not SQLExpress.

I have observe the in View connection properties that instance name field is blank.

so I need to access the database with IP not system name because different domain not recognize system name. It only recognize only IP address.

I need the below details for connectivity.

```
servername : 172.27.28.44 or 172.27.28.44\SQLEXPRESS
username : sa
password : blablabla
```

Please resolve my issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have a working network configuration and the server is reachable. Try `telnet server-ip 1433` to see if it's reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the client connecting to your database server has 1433 outbound from their location. Also like MicSim says, see if you can connect from a client that you know has 1433 outbound open.

Also if you are trying \SQLEXPRESS you may want to verify UDP 1434 and SQL Browser service and/or verify that \SQLEXPRESS is not using a port other than 1433.